# Where should I start looking if I want to implement my own custom search?

Tags: search

I want to implement a search in WP based on elastic search.
Ive been looking around to find the best way to replacethe default search but when googling  I mainly get plugins. I tried looking at the API, but I havent found anything meaningful.

Where should I start looking if I want to implement my own custom search?

Comment: a god starting point may be to look at the source code of those plugins.